# Reading file line by line increasing memory?

Tags: c

I'm new to c. I have some code I'm trying to test out in Cuda but am having bit of trouble pulling the data in.  My data resides in a file(19GB) and I basically plan to read certain number of lines save them to a list, send them to process and do this again for the whole file.

I'm at the very beginning of learning how to do this and having issue with C that I'm not sure about, when I run the program my memory keeps increasing(when I go to activity monitor on my mac), but it is doesn't seem to be tied to the c program, it just shows inactive memory growing and growing. Even after the program stops the memory is still inactive(only way to get it back is to reboot).  As far as I can tell it doesn't impact the program but seems strange and I'm curious to know why and if/what I can do about it?

I have a little understanding of malloc and free(sorry I know Java/Python better and never had to do this) but I am not sure if I am suppose to do it in this code because I thought the `line` variable keeps getting overwritten.

Here's the code:

```
int main() {
    printf("Starting..");
    char line[1024];
    FILE *fp = fopen("output.txt","r");

    if( fp == NULL ) {
        return 1;
    }
    int count = 0;
    while( fgets(line,1024,fp) ) {
        //printf("%s\n",line);
        count++;
    }
    printf(" num of lines is %i \n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any tips/suggestions on what's going on here and if there's a better way to do this?

Update: I'm sorry, I didn't mention, the behavior I notice is while the program is running.  As it runs the inactive memory just keeps growing and growing.  I have about 4 gigs free and after 30 seconds its all full and rebooting is the only way to free it(even if the c program is killed memory is not freed).

Comment: Probably some sort of caching done by the OS to reduce disk access. Just a wild guess, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. Making memory free takes effort. This effort is totally wasted because as soon as the memory is needed, the system just has to remove it from the free pool. It's much more efficient to directly transition the memory from one use to another. So the system is being smart rather than stupid.

It's not like if you use half as much memory today you can use twice as much tomorrow. So there is no benefit to making memory free.

When you go to read lines from the file, the operating system reads in entire blocks from the file. It tries to keep those blocks in memory, if possible, because that allows it to avoid having to read from the disk in the future. If it has no better use to put the memory to, it keeps those file blocks in memory. That both saves it the effort of having to make the memory free just to make the memory used again and it speeds up any future accesses to that same block of the file.

There is no benefit to making this memory free. It just takes effort on the part of the OS to make it free, effort on the part of the OS to make it used again in the future, and the OS loses the opportunity to avoid disk reads. So making the memory free would be complete stupidity.

Comment: This is what I don't understand, if each line I'm reading is a constant size then why is the memory growing? shouldn't the variable line just keep getting replaced with the data from the next line and memory size stay constant?

Comment: I'll update my answer with more details. It has nothing to do with what you're doing but with what you're making the OS do.

Comment: ahh. so its basically caching it as the file grows? That would explain why the memory is not associated with the program yet memory just keeps growing.  But this leads me to more questions, Can I disable it if I don't need previous blocks? After my program is done why is it not being released?  If its OS specific then don't worry about answering those questions(since I plan to run it on multiple OS's..mac for testing, linux after that).

Comment: Can you disable it? Yes. See `posix_fadvise`. (This can be good because your program may force useful data out of cache.) Why is it not being released? Read my last paragraph. That would be stupid. (It takes work to release it, and all it does is force the OS to go to effort to make it used again when it's used.)

Comment: I'll look up posix_fadvise.  Sorry when I said released I didn't mean during the life of the program but I mean after the program is done. After the program is no longer running that memory is not avail for any of my other programs to use, thats what I meant. (btw, thanks for teaching me so much today..)

Comment: That memory absolutely is available for your other programs to use. What makes you think it's not?! And my argument about why it's stupid to release it has nothing whatsoever to do with whether a program is running or not. It applies equally well if *no* programs are running.

Comment: I read up a bit on inactive memory in mac and I think your right David(not that I doubted you for a second).  Your logic makes sense and I'll play around a bit more to figure things out. Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not allocate any memory (except that of the `FILE` struct) so you do not have any leak that depends on the file size.

However, you *do* leak some memory because you forgot to `fclose(fp);` after being done accessing the file.

As a suggestion, in case you are on linux, use `valgrind --leak-check=full ./yourapp` - assuming that your program is compiled with debugging symbols (the `-g` switch in gcc) you will get a detailed leak report showing exactly if/where your program leaks memory.

Comment: I can fix the fclose problem but this problem seems to happen while the program is running.  Because the file is huge it takes some time to run and as it runs I see the memory grow in size. Could it be leaking somewhere else?

Comment: Also, thanks for suggesting valgrind.never heard of it before but I just ran it(on my mac) and its pretty sweet. It didn't find the leak though, even though the memory that it was allocating during the test still has not gotten freed.

Answer (score 1):

its because your using

```
    fgets(buffer, int size, file);
```

which will only stop reading if you hit EOF.  Theres 2 ways of fixing it, either use

```
    while(fgets(buffer, size, file) != EOF){};
```

or

```
    while(fread(buffer, sizeof(char), nmem, file) < 1024){};
```

I recommend using the latter, for some reason I tend to run into issues using fgets, and you have more control of what your doing with fread.

Comment: Thanks timkd127, I'm testing out your suggestion but I'm unsure what `nmem` is?  I tried to look it up and couldn't find anything. What is it? Do I need to import any library to use it?

Comment: by the way, not sure about the second method but with the first method you suggested I still have the same problem.

Comment: No thats my fault i should have been more clear.  nmem is the number of chunks of memory (parameter 2, in this case char) that you want to read at a time. Its generally set to the size of the buffer youre using, so in this case 1024.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and now got a weirder result, it exits right away saying the file size is 0(I check file size as a way of making sure its reading the entire file). I put this in my while loop `while(fread(line, sizeof(char), 1024, fp) < 1024){` in my code above

Comment: hmmmmm, that may actually answer why both methods arent working.  Are would you be able to post youre "output.txt" file.  If its empty there is no EOF so fgets would read forever and fread would return 0.

Comment: its a massive file but here's a sample of a line(the numbers change and this is repeated enough times to fill a 19 GB file): `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2],`

Comment: Welp im officially stumped.  My next best guess is that it is an operating system related issue, but knowing nothing about macs im useless in that department.  Sorry i couldnt be more help.

Comment: no worries, you have helped me a lot by giving me plenty to research and learn about. I think David's answer seems most plausible, that the OS is caching the data.  Thanks a lot for taking the time to help a total n00b like me(I upvoted your answer)